# Can Slack Share Only One Window Or Part Of Screen?

Tags: screencasts, slack

Any way to share only one window or part of screen during Slack screen share?

Comment: There is an answer over at Unix&Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503206/300994

Comment: Looks like a workaround for Linux only. Still better than nothing I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. [Slack documentation](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/115003501303-Share-your-screen-with-Slack-Calls) doesn't specify any way to share only one window or part of screen. Also within the slack software, there isn't any visible option provided to achieve this.

Comment: Unlike Wikipedia, we appreciate it when users contribute their personal knowledge — especially when you know how to do something tricky, or a risk in doing something, or anything else that other people can independently verify.   Negative statements like “No, … there isn't any way” can’t be verified experimentally.   Can you link to a reference that backs up your claim?

Comment: Thanks, I have added link to Slack documentation. I understand what you mean. If no one has posted answer in 8 months doesn't mean "there isn't any way". Rather it may be that "no one has yet found a way". However in this case, I had Googled and gone through slack's documentation before posting the answer. Also have been using Slack for at least 2 years now.